# Platform independent go build for engineer testing

Tags: go, e2e-testing, endly

My typical [endly](http://github.com/viant/endly/) test automation is parametrized to takes place either on my localhost(osx) or on staging box (linux), ideally I want to build separately cross platform app binary.

All that said when I build my app binary on OSX for linux, I am seeing the following

```
export GOOS=linux
go build
# github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/api


../../../../github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/api/api.go:17:9: undefined: SQLSMALLINT
../../../../github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/api/api.go:18:9: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT
../../../../github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/api/api.go:19:9: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT
```

My application uses odbc to connect to vertica, and at the moment the only available Vertica driver in go uses CGO, 
**Is there a way to build cross platform CGO independent, statically compiled app?**

Answer (score 2):

While there are definitely ways of doing this manually, I'd recommend you to use [xgo](https://github.com/karalabe/xgo). I've successfully used it in a project which involved using [zserge/webview](https://github.com/zserge/webview), and [the gitea project](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea) uses it for cross-compiling release binaries (which involve using SQLite, which requires cgo).

Keep in mind it requires Docker, and it needs to download a very large image, but there is a good wrapper around all the commands that you need to run.

```
# installing the wrapper
go get github.com/karalabe/xgo
# go into your repo, and then run this to crosscompile!
xgo --targets=windows/*,darwin/*,linux/amd64
```